# How does a refractive index of less than one not violate relativity?

Tags: special-relativity, optics, speed-of-light, refraction, faster-than-light

If I am not mistaken, [this video](https://youtu.be/JZOn1B8K8mA) says that X-rays travel faster in glass than in a vacuum. Special Relativity says that information can not travel faster than the speed of light in a vacuum, so what is keeping us from making Tachyon Phones with glass and x-rays?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/436329/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/76663/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What travels faster than light is the phase ([phase velocity](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_velocity)), not the envelope of the x-ray beam. The waveform travels with the [group velocity](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_velocity) which is less than $c$.

Information is encoded into the waveform therefore it's transfered with the group velocity.

Phase velocity do not transfer information hence no tachyon phones

Comment: RF waveguides (hollow tubes that conduct RF power, usually in the GHz region) have the same property -- the phase velocity is higher than $c$, but the group velocity is lower.